# Marketing Cloud custom report generation

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

When sending one Email Template to a specific segment (Data Extension) we use an AMPScript and this email is being sent in several languages based on the attribute `language__c` from our master DE - `Acc_Synchronized`.

We have combined stats (# of sent, # of opened, # of clicked).

As we want to evaluate the effectiveness of our translations and also check how different languages or countries respond to the communication, we need to have some way of picking the raw data from MC and export it to spreadsheets, so we can see the stats mentioned above divided into two client’s attributes - language and billing country.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to leverage [send logging](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000333925&type=1) to record the language and country.

Then you can incorporate the data recorded into your query activities.

NOTE: If you haven't [created](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_create_email_sendlogging_de.htm&type=5) a Send Log data extension, don't forget to add a reasonable row-based retention period to it.